# django admin site models not showing

Tags: django, django-admin

i have a site with django, is showing a basic view, and the admin site,

but when i log into the admin site i cannot see the models:
[image]

this are my models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published') 
    class Admin:
        pass




class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField()
    class Admin:
        pass
```

so im referencing the admin from my db scheme,

but cannot see this tables in my admin,

what is missing?

thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to create a file called `admin.py` and [register any models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) you want to be accessible from the Django admin:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myproject.myapp.models import MyModel

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Comment: No need for the ModelAdmin subclass if you're not overriding anything - `admin.site.register(MyModel)` works fine.